# If $ \nabla^2 f(x) \geq mI$ Show that $\|x-x^*\|_2 \leq \frac{\||\nabla f(x)||}{m}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given that f is a strongly convex function:$ \nabla^2 f(x) \geq mI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $m>0$

Show that $||x-x^*||_2 \leq \frac{||\nabla f(x)||_2}{m}$ for all x where x* is is the global min argument of f

This was part of a two part question:

The first part required to prove that $f(x)-f(x^*) \leq \frac{1}{2m}||\nabla f(x)||_2^2$

I proved this by employing theinequality:
$f(y) \geq f(x)+ \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{m}{2}||y-x||$

minimizing both left hand sides of the inequality with respect to y such that:

$0=\nabla f(x)+m(y^*-x) \Leftrightarrow y^*-x=\frac{-1}{m}\nabla f(x)$

plugging back into the inequality and rearranging completes the proof

I suspect a similar manipulation needs to be performed for the other proof but i cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Hint: strong convexity implies that $$f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^T (x - y) + \frac{m}{2} \| x - y \|^2, \; \forall x, y.$$
Now apply that inequality with the appropriate $x$ and $y$ and rearrange.

Comment: @VHarisop Yes I am attempting to use that inequality. However, I am struggling with obtaining the needed form. Could you please demonstrate?

Comment: @AdamKordab What have you tried so far? Feel free to edit your original post and we can pick up from the place where you are currently stuck.

Comment: @VHarisop This is where I am at so far.  I am unsure on how to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already shown that $f(x) - f(x^*) \leq \frac{1}{2m} \|\nabla f(x) \|^2$, it suffices to show the following lower bound:

$$
f(x) - f(x^*) \geq \frac{m}{2} \| x - x^* \|^2.
$$

This inequality follows immediately from $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ and the standard inequality you used to obtain the previous bound:

$$
f(x) \geq f(x^*) + \nabla f(x^*)^T(x - x^*) + \frac{m}{2} \|x - x^*\|^2.
$$

Finally, combine the two bounds to obtain

$$
\frac{m}{2} \|x - x^*\|^2 \leq f(x) - f(x^*) \leq \frac{1}{2m} \| \nabla f(x)\|^2 \Rightarrow
\|x - x^* \|^2 \leq \frac{1}{m^2} \| \nabla f(x) \|^2.
$$